# why does my code detect a decimal as not a numerical value

Tags: python

When I type in 23.3 and 44 it outputs  only one of these values is  a valid number
And a Valid number basically  is any number that has no strings
how can I fix this where 23.3 and 44 outputs both are values

```
x = input(":")
y = input(":")
if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    print('both are valid numbers')
elif  x.isnumeric() or y.isnumeric():
    print('one of the values  is a valid number ')
else: print('none are valid numbers')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Comment: above will not address float but this might be an answer: [How to check if a raw input is an integer or float (including negatives) without using try-except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543550/how-to-check-if-a-raw-input-is-an-integer-or-float-including-negatives-without)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a raw input is an integer or float (including negatives) without using try-except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543550/how-to-check-if-a-raw-input-is-an-integer-or-float-including-negatives-without)

Answer (score 0):

The `isnumeric` method does not return True for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

`isnumeric()` only checks whether the value is an integer, but not if it is a float.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a very clean way to handle this. I think the best solution is to implement your own function, maybe something like this:

```py
def is_decimal(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

x = input(":")
y = input(":")
if is_decimal(x) and is_decimal(y):
    print('both are valid numbers')
elif is_decimal(x) or is_decimal(y):
    print('one of the values is a valid number ')
else: print('none are valid numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_number(s):
if s.count(".")==1:   
    if s[0]=="-":
        s=s[1:]
    if s[0]==".":
        return False
    s=s.replace(".","")
    for i in s:
        if i not in "0123456789":
            return False
    else:                
        return True
elif s.count(".")==0:  
    if s[0]=="-":
        s=s[1:]
    for i in s:
        if i not in "0123456789":
            return False
    else:
        return True
else:
    return False
```

x = input(":")
y = input(":")
if is_number(x) and is_number(y):
print('both are valid numbers')
elif  is_number(x) or is_number(y):
print('one of the values  is a valid number ')
else: print('none are valid numbers')

Comment: beause the ‘.’ does not return True，so you can try my code

Answer (score -1):

This is the description of [str.isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.isnumeric) in the documentation.

> Return True if there is at least one character in the string and all characters are numeric characters, False otherwise.

So it can't determine float directly.

You can use a regular expression to determine whether it is a float.

[re](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$")

x = input(":")
y = input(":")


def is_numeric(s: str):
    return s.isnumeric() or regex.match(s)


x_is_numeric = is_numeric(x)
y_is_numeric = is_numeric(y)
if x_is_numeric and y_is_numeric:
    print('both are valid numbers')
elif x_is_numeric or y_is_numeric:
    print('one of the values  is a valid number ')
else:
    print('none are valid numbers')
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.